# How does QGIS "Update SQL layer" in Server mode

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-server

I have a [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) 3.22 project with a single vector layer coming from a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) (PG:14-3.2) database.

When I right click on the layer in the table of content > "Update SQL layer", I can see an SQL-like query in a window, along with some options.

[image: Update SQL window]
*Fig.1. The "Update SQL Layer..." window.*

From this, and because this query is taking some minutes(!) on a large data set, I am pretty sure that it is a *true* SQL query and that QGIS will actually *send* it to the database to fetch data.
So this query is executed *by* the database itself and is therefore not internally handled by QGIS (please fix me if I'm wrong in my understanding).

Now, in that "Update SQL" window, I can also change the query according to my wishes, in order to refresh the data that I can see in the layer of my project, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT
  p.id,
  st_force2d(p.geom) as position,
  p.attr1,
  r.attr2,
  r.attr3 
FROM "public"."mytable" p
LEFT JOIN "public"."related" r
ON p.id = r.fk_p_id
WHERE p.range < 100
ORDER BY p.range
```

this allows me to:

1. limit the number of retrieved attributes,
2. make use of any PostgreSQL and/or PostGIS functions to modify these attributes,
3. create complex results by using SQL JOIN with other tables of the database,
4. ...

This is really great to refresh a layer in Desktop mode, but it can be time consuming depending on the functions or the joins which are used.

#### Question

But then, when used in Server mode, especially for serving features using WFS3, how is QGIS dealing with that query and all its options?
Especially, how exactly does it handle database updates (in case the data but not the structure of the database is modified)?
i.e. what mechanisms precisely occur under the hood?

**EDIT:**

Because it may be quite complex to build an answer depending on the involved mechanisms, here are some closely related questions I'm asking myself right now (and for which I don't necessarily want to open one thread each):

When run in server mode, will QGIS refresh the layer (i.e. re-run the same query) on a regular frequency, e.g. every X seconds / minutes / hours? (this can be extremely resource and time consuming on the database side)

It seems it does not create a view in the database because I cannot see any, e.g. when using pgAdmin at the exact same time, but there is this option, named "☐ Avoid selecting by feature ID" which tells by mouse-hover:
[image]
So it's definitely not clear to me...

Or will QGIS cache the data locally (to the RAM for example)?

In the two latter cases (view/cache), if yes, then how does it deal with database updates (e.g. by users of a web application for example)? Could it be that it will "miss" some new data for ever / for a certain amount of time?

And finally, is it possible to tell QGIS how and when to refresh the layer? For example, by "listening to some specific changes".

Comment: If QGIS server works like other WMS servers it is much more simple. The data for the output image is queried from the database when requested. Turn the statement logging on in your database and you should see a new query every time when WMS client is doing a GetMap request and nothing at all in between.

Comment: RE refreshing of layers: When using the QGIS desktop, it will not refresh the layer unless explicitely told to, but there is a setting on the layer under Rendering  that will tell QGIS to refresh (any layer) at a given frequency - I would guess the same is the case for QGIS server - although I have never used that part myself.